# Query by distance between two objects without using Oracle Spatial functionality?

Tags: java, sql, jpa, spatial, oracle-spatial

Right now I have table in Oracle 10g database with `LAT(FLOAT)` and `LNG(FLOAT)` columns.

Task is to find all entries within a specific distance (radius) of a given point (center). Application itself is in Java, Hibernate is used as JPA implementation.

After some research I've found that Oracle Spatial needs to be used. However, there is no way to convert my columns to `SDO_GEOMETRY`, so I am not able to use Oracle's `SDO_WITHIN_DISTANCE` function.

Is there any workaround to implement such functionality?

Currently I am just querying all entries and iterating over them with Haversine formula - and this will become bottleneck very soon :-)

Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: You can always implement haversine alghorithm

Comment: @JakubKania Thanks for your reply! I am currently using Haversine algorithm, however it's not precise enough - I need to check distances (500 -> 5000) meters and it's failing to provide accurate results..

Comment: You can't directly convert the columns, but can't you alter the table to include a new column of spatial type and calculate it from the values within Lat and Lng???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't change the columns on the target table, you could use a trigger to materialise the data in a separate table as an sdo_geometry, use sdo_within_distance and then join the rows to your original table.

Comment: Well seems like trigger was the most "elegant" solution for this case. Thanks @Ben !

Answer (score 1):

Using existing spatial data encoded in X and Y columns without introducing additional columns is easy: just use a function-based index.

This means no change on the existing tables: just adding a function and the function-based index together with possibly a view to make everything more transparent.

See the full answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/92554/can-i-create-an-oracle-spatial-view-from-a-non-spatial-table/92599)